# Windows Phone Calendar Like RedBus.in App

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, calendar

Just now I've seen the RedBus.in App in Windows Phone Store, in that app the calendar is very simple and looking cool.

So Now I'm planing to do same calender in my app.[image]

Can anyone suggest me how can I do it? RedBus App [LINK](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/store/app/redbus-in/b3803839-bfdd-428e-89cb-88c0fdfe2429)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out https://wpcontrols.codeplex.com/

You can style your UI elements and make it more neat. You can add confirm and cancel as `ApplicationBarButtons` on the bottom to make it look more beautiful and consistent with the Windows Phone UI.

On the other hand, `Telerik` offers some really good controls, if you can buy it.

http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls/calendar.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with [WPControls](https://wpcontrols.codeplex.com/)?
it is an amazing control  if i were you , i would use this control :)
[image]

Answer (score -1):

they have customized it you can use Kendo ui TO GET THAT using JS